# Circular Queue claims an unretrieved item would be overwritten

Tags: java, queue, circular-buffer

```
class CircularQueue{
    private char q[];
    private int putloc, getloc;

    public CircularQueue(int size){
      q = new char[size+1];
      putloc = getloc = 0;
    }

    public void put (char ch) {
      if (putloc+1==getloc | ((putloc ==q.length-1) & (getloc==0))) {
        System.out.println ("Queue is full.");
        return;
      }
      putloc++;
      if(putloc==q.length) putloc = 0;
      q[putloc] = ch;
    }

    public char get() {
      if (getloc == putloc){
        System.out.println("Queue is empty.");
        return (char) 0;
      }

      getloc++;
      if(getloc==q.length) getloc =0;
      return q[getloc];
    }
  }
```

I don't understand when the queue would be full.

If `putloc == q.length-1`, it would be at the end of an array.
`getloc == 0` would be at the beginning of the array.
So if `put()` was called it would do `putloc++` and go to `q[0]` and put a value there.
They claim it would overwrite a value at `q[0]` but if `getloc == 0` then that means it already returned a value from that part of the array.
`q[getloc]` immediately follows `getloc++` so once `getloc == 0` it will get a value from `q[0]` leaving that space empty for putting new values.
So the next time `get()` is called it would get a value from `q[1]`.

Can someone please explain where my logic is wrong?

Comment: I suggest you write a test case that proves it works the way you think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your claim: "if `getloc == 0` then that means it already returned a value from that part of the array." The problem is that this is not always true. In the `put()` function, you have the condition `if (putloc+1==getloc || ((putloc ==q.length-1) && (getloc==0)))`. If the array was full, but no one had ever called `get()`, then `((putloc ==q.length-1) && (getloc==0))` would equal `true`, without any values ever being returned.

Two other things to fix:

-Use `&&` and `||`, not `&` and `|`. Two marks means a Boolean operation, one mark is for bit manipulation.
-This code as written is not threadsafe. If one thread called `get()` and another called `put()` simulataneously, `getloc` and/or `putloc` are not going to be accurate. To solve this, I'd use `synchronized`:

```
public void put (char ch) {
    synchronized(q) {
      if (putloc+1==getloc | ((putloc ==q.length-1) & (getloc==0))) {
        System.out.println ("Queue is full.");
        return;
      }
      putloc++;
      if(putloc==q.length) putloc = 0;
      q[putloc] = ch;
   }
}

public char get() {
  synchronized(q) {
      if (getloc == putloc){
        System.out.println("Queue is empty.");
        return (char) 0;
      }

      getloc++;
      if(getloc==q.length) getloc =0;
      return q[getloc];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  If putloc == q.length-1 then would it have put a value in q[0]?  The first value that is put is q[1].  So if putloc==q.length-1 couldn't it still put a value at q[0]?  In that case getloc==0 and wouldn't the first value it gets be q[1]?

Comment: You're right, hadn't thought of that. So your logic actually seems pretty sound (but be sure to make the Boolean operator and `synchronized` corrections I suggested). Who/what exactly is saying that "an unretrieved item would be overwritten"?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, I was working the problem out on paper.  The book states "In a circular queue, the queue is full not when the end of the underlying array is reached, but rather when storing an item would cause an unretrieved item to be overwritten." while explaining the logic behind the put() conditions.

Comment: If I went by my logic than putloc == getloc for it to be full.  Then putloc would have just put a value at q[0] which getloc just returned.  This would be confusing since you can't put a value at q[0] until one is returned freeing that space up.  These are also the conditions for the queue being empty.  So I understand their logic, just not why they claim the quote I quoted above.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the Wikipedia article on cicular buffers (aka queues) at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer. Seems that a problem that these data structures always have is that both empty and full queues will have putloc == getloc. Use a boolean to keep track of whether or not the queue is really empty.